# How to filter a Font Character in php

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have an arial character giving me a headache. `U+02DD` turns into a question mark after I turn its document into a phpquery object. What is an efficient method for removing the character in php by referring to it as `'U+02DD'`?

Comment: Is this the only character you are having problems with?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by turning a document into a phpquery object. Do any of these sound like the issue you're having? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+char+php+question-mark

Comment: @NULLUSER: It has been the biggest headache, but no. I have a document coming in as ISO-8859-1 and I believe it is Arial. The open and close quotation marks are both causing trouble. Everything else seems fine, but the test sample is too small for a definitive set of problem characters.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "document in Arial". Do not confuse character encoding with a font that is used to render characters on screen.

Comment: @deceze - Thanks, I'm currently reading this article to fill in my knowledge gaps: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and do it like this:

```
$str = "your text with that character";

echo preg_replace("#\x{02DD}#u", "", $str); //EDIT: inserted the u tag for unicode
```

To refer to large unicode ranges, you can use preg_replace and specify the unicode character with `\x{abcd}` pattern. The second parameter is an empty string that. This will make preg_replace to replace your character with nothing, effectively removing it.

---

**[EDIT] Another way**:

Did you try doing `htmlentities` on it. As it's html-entity is `&#733;`, doing that OR replacing the character by `&#733;` may solve your issue too. Like this:

```
echo preg_replace("#\x{02DD}#u", "&#733;", $str);
```

Comment: The preg_replace method returned this warning:  preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset 7. I copy and pasted your pattern.

Comment: @JMC, Sorry I forgot to put the trailing `u` tag (for unicode) in the preg_replace. I have updated the code. It will not give any error now and will successfully replace it.

Comment: If I wanted to use preg_replace on "&#733;" how would I write the expression?

Comment: @JMC. Updated the answer for "how to write with `&#733;`".

Answer (score 4):

You can use iconv() to convert character sets and strip invalid characters.

```
<?PHP
 /* This will convert ISO-8859-1 input to UTF-8 output and 
  * strip invalid characters
  */
 $output = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $input);

 /* This will attempt to convert invalid characters to something
  * that looks approximately correct.
  */
 $output = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $input);
?>
```

See the iconv() documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: +1 this is a good suggestion. I had to use this in combination with shamittomar's answer to send the fancy quote mark back into the ground where it belongs. I believe it is a spawn of satan.